# TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later) couldn't get size: 0x0000000000000e

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, microcode

Hi first of all i'm a first time user and a newbs in this computer thing.

So i try to install linux on my windows laptop and it gave  the eror:

```
TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)*  
couldn't get size: 0x0000000000000e
```

My laptop is Asus X450J:

Intel® Core™ i7 4700HQ Processor,

Intel® HM86 Express Chipset

8GB DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, up to 16 G

NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 745M 2GB DDR3

​

I have updated my bios in the asus website:

https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X450JF/HelpDesk_BIOS/

and also try the solution from:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/92uxbf/unable_to_install_ubuntu_firmware_bug_tsc_deadline/

​

yet nothing works, any suggestion?

Edited:
First thank you for the input.

1. Are you booting off of a CD? A USB? How did you create the USB?

USB, i created with Rufus 3.6 bootable from ISO file

2.When does this error occur? What solution did you try from the redit thread?

it happened when I try to install ubuntu or try ubuntu everytime. the solution i try from reddit is this:

- Boot the usb and press arrow down for "install ubuntu"
- Press "E"
- go down to the linux line and press END-key
- write ACPI=off nomodeset
- press F10 to restart

But nothing changes

3. Are you first booting into the "try Ubuntu" and installing from there or are choosing "install Ubuntu" from the menu that appears when you boot?

I tried all of the methods:
a. "try Ubuntu" resulted in same error.
b. install ubuntu also resulted in same eror

When I wait out the process (after screen showing TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata....) lots of programming line seems flashing really fast after that it enters a screen with ubuntu and loading dots but after that nothing happen.

The installation is done with USB. I also tried with Linux mint but the results remain the same. I also try to redownload the installation from the website and redo the process but nothing changes.

Comment: @karel the only solutions given there are to update the BIOS (which the OP has already done) and to install something which obviously cannot be done before installing the actual operating system. So I don't think this is a dupe since this one is blocking installation while the dupe appears on an already installed system.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you are doing. Are you booting off of a CD? A USB? How did you create the USB? When does this error occur? What solution did you try from the redit thread? Are you first booting into the "try Ubuntu" and installing from there or are choosing "install Ubuntu" from the menu that appears when you boot? Please make sure your edit includes the answers to all of these. The more you tell us, the better your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for editing, but as I said, we need all the answers. You just answered the first (and least important) question. We really want to help, but we can't if you don't explain what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer! The first thing is to try the steps from the redit post ***but*** instead of restarting in the end, press b (the b key) to boot with the changes you made. Does that work? If not, you can generating the USB with another tool instead of Rufus. I have had similar issues resolved in the past by that simple change. I doubt it will work here, to be honest, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @terdon Hi, I can't really explained what just happened. the  eror was showing at first, then screen was flashing with codes really fast, and  then itseems like frozen, it looks like failing  but then it worked! I just want to say thank you very much, this post is my hail mary pass for linux after trying the past two days. Now unto learning how to use linux.

 once again, thank you!

Comment: ah, great! I'm glad it worked,but I'm not sure what worked :) could you post an answer explaining what you did? That way the question can be marked as answered. Or did it just work by itself without any changes?

Answer (score 0):

first of all take this with a grain of salt. I'm a first time user and doesn't really know why it works but this is what i have done.

1. try to update your bios, if your on a laptop your manufacturer might have the program to update.
2. Boot the usb and press arrow down for "install ubuntu"
3. Press "E" or B
4. go down to the linux line and press END-key
5. write ACPI=off nomodeset
6. press F10 to restart

after doing this you might still see the eror. What i do is I wait it out. It doesn't worked the first time but then is worked. Hope the best for you!

PS: although my linux is working, when booting the entry screen just flashing realy fast for about 5 seconds. The kind that makes people get seizure and dizzy. I still don't know why, but one problem at a time.